# what is correct syntax for partial specialization of template template

Tags: c++, templates

Hi can anyone please explain what is the correct syntax for partial specialization of template template? or is it even possible? any help is much appreciated

```
template < typename A >
class X
{


};

template < typename B >
class Y
{


};

template < template< typename > class U, class T >
class Z
{   
    // there are other methods in class which i don't want to replicate
    void func();  // want to specialize this for class X
};

template < template< typename > class U, class T >
void Z< U, T >::func()
{
    std::cout << " this is done ";
}

// specialize this for X
template < template< typename > class U, class T >
void Z< X, T >::func()
{

}
```

Comment: isn't it a class template

Comment: Yes it is, sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot specialise just a part of a class template. When you partially specialise a class template, you need to provide the entire declaration, not just a single function.

And you cannot partially specialise a function template.

You might be able to do what you want with inheritance. You could collect the shared methods in a base class, and then define a templated derived class with a partial specialisation for the methods with exceptions.

Comment: how about if i make func also a template template function

Comment: then also it will not work since we can't partial specialize function templates